# How to set custom background in Android?

Tags: android

I want a functionality in my app in which the user could select a background(`.png/.jpg` file) from the phone's memory. I guess 80% of my task has been completed by using this link http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/190013-creating-simple-file-chooser/

The code from the above link just shows the view of SD card and now I want to set any image file present there as my app background. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Actually for getting correct you guys have to follow two answers here one is appserv's answer which i have selected but for exact solution have a look at the conversation between me and a.ch...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just select image and set background, I think the simpliest way is something like this:

```
.....
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
....

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case SELECT_PICTURE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                    setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
                }
                cursor.close();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: look at my comment for a.ch's answer. I think you close to sol.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your app, a [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) around every existing layout, begun with an ImageView that you set appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it dynamically use

```
setBackgroundColor(int color)
```

or

```
setBackgroundResource(int resourceID)
```

on your parentview of your activity.

Comment: Sorry but the thing i'm pointing is not that easy that you might be thinking of.

Answer (score 0):

Yuo can try this:

```
Bitmap srcBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(new File("path/to/file.jpg")));
BitmapDrawable bmpDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(srcBitmap);
YourView.setBackgroundDrawable(bmpDrawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your problem is that you don't know how to load image picked from a gallery. @appserv's answer solves your problem, but if you need to load images from any source (including your app resources), look at how it is [implemented in ImageView](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/widget/ImageView.java#ImageView.resolveUri%28%29)

Comment: Actually i have created a menu item named setBackground which upon getting clicked will open a dialog having two buttons 1. set custom background 2. default background. When the user will click on first the phone memory loc or SDCarddir (whatever) should open up and then user could select the pics present there now the app should have the new background and also by using second button user could switch to default one.

Comment: This is exactly what appserv's solution does, except restoring the default background. Put the code related to `startActivityForResult(..)` in your `onContextItemSelected(..)` method.

Comment: thanks but issue is whom should get credit? :) you or appserv